# Iron Pyhton not showing up in visual studio community when starting a new project femplate

Tags: python, visual-studio, development-environment

I'm new to the world of python and programming in general.

I wrote my first project in virtual studio code and then a friend suggested that I switch over to visual studio community as I'm looking to build applications from my python code.

I'm ready to build a GUI and from my research the best option seems to be iron python.

When I installed iron python and followed the youtube video instructions the problem started which is iron python does not show up in the project template section.

I cant find any posts about this issue outside of one I found from 2010 with VS 2010 version.  I did follow those steps in the post and the result is the same.

Here's what I've tried.

1. Uninstall python developer in VS
2. Uninstall iron python
3. Reinstall both
4. Run repair on VS installer

Nothing seems to work.  I'm open to suggestions.

Also if anyone else has suggestions for another way to make a GUi from python code in VS I'm open to that as well.

Thank you!

Comment: Bit of a long shot, but you can try clearing the project template cache by closing VS, deleting `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\1*\ProjectTemplatesCache_{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}`, and restarting VS.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion  Unfortunately the long shot didn't pan out.  I just tried it and still the same problem